# Extracting a string after each number

Tags: .net, regex

I have to extract a string. The string consist of both numbers and text. Below is the example

```
1. This is a test string that needs to be parsed based on numbers 2. This is a second test string that needs to be split based on numbers 3. This is the Third string that contains numbers like 1. 2., but this is also part of the string 4. This is the fourth string that has the mix of numbers and alphabets, this needs to be slit too <line Feed>
```

I need to split this string between the number and text

so

```
1 and This is a test string that needs to be parsed based on numbers 
2 and This is a second test string that needs to be split based on numbers 
3 and  This is the Third string that contains numbers like 1. 2., but this is also part of the string
4 and This is the fourth string that has the mix of numbers and alphabets, this needs to be slit too
```

any help will be appreciated

Comment: not possible. there is NO way for code to differentiate between `1.`-to-be-split an `1.`-should-remain-embedded. Garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: It is possible if it follows some sort of format. Do the lines always start with the number like in your example?

Comment: @MarcB is correct. Regex has no capability to do what you're asking, unless the numbers to be split are differentiated from the numbers that aren't to be split. If, for example, your line 3's embedded numbers didn't have periods following them, you'd have something to work with.

Comment: you may have a SLIGHT chance, if your embedded "don't split" numbers are always LESS than the current line's `#.`. At least at that point you could keep track of which line number you're on and only split if the in-consideration number is less than that line number. But that's not something regex is geared to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
\s(?=\d+\.\s*This)
```

Try this.Couldnt find any other matching pattern.Had to use `This`.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/pD5sV6/11

Comment: Yeah, that would work assuming every string had a `This` at the start, but I'm pretty sure that's just an artifact of their example.

Comment: The above was just an example. Not every line starts with This